# Is there a way to run build_runner only for a specific target?

Tags: flutter, build-runner

My `build.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    # ...
  drift:
    # ...
  go_router:
    # ...
  ferry:
    # ...
```

If I only make a change that will impact drift for example, I'd like to only build for this target but I couldn't find any option for it. Is this possible?

If I use enable: true/false for each, it deletes the generated files by this builder. I'd like to avoid that.